# Video input redirecting after upload in Instagram Direct Message - React.JS App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, file-upload, instagram

Thanks in advance for the help.

**User Experience:**

-User is in Instagram and sends a link to another user via direct message. 
Example: https://www.doingthingsmedia.com

-Recipient clicks on link and begins to fill out the form.

-Recipient completes info before file upload question.

-At file upload, they are redirected to their photos/videos. Respondent selects the video, and the file is compressed.

*Here is where the issue is:* 
-Recipient is redirected to the landing page without hitting submit or completing the form.

This does not happen on mobile regularly. 
I feel like this might have something to do with Instagram's redirect.

Here is the event that happens upon upload:

handleFileChange = async event => {
    const file = event.currentTarget.files[0];

```
if (!file.type.includes('video/')) {
  this.setState({ notAVideo: true });
  return;
}
const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);

await this.setState({ objectUrl });

this.video.preload = 'metadata';
this.video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
  const duration = this.video.duration;
  if (duration <= 60) {
    this.file = file;
    this.setState({ videoTooLong: false, notAVideo: false });
  } else {
    this.setState({ videoTooLong: true });
  }
 };
 };
```

Here is what is rendered:

```
          <div className="video-upload-container full-width">
        {errors.videoInvalid ? <span style={{color: 'red'}}>Please Upload a Video</span> : null}
        {videoUpload && (
          <div className="video-wrapper">
            <label htmlFor="file-upload" className="file-upload-label">
              Upload Your Video
              <input
                id="file-upload"
                type="file"
                className="video-upload upload-btn"
                onChange={this.handleFileChange}
              />
            </label>
            {videoTooLong && <p className="warning">Please upload videos one minute or less</p>}
            {notAVideo && <p className="warning">Please upload a VIDEO</p>}
            <video
              controls
              width="500px"
              id="vid"
              className="video-controller"
              src={objectUrl}
              ref={input => {
                this.video = input;
              }}
            />
          </div>
```

Any suggestions you have are very helpful! Thanks!